# How to get the first day of the month expressed in Unix timestamp

Tags: solidity, remix

I need to compare `block.timestamp` with the UNIX timestamp of the first day of the month. Any idea on how to do that in Solidity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an external library such as [this one](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary/) that does most of the work for you. But it takes a toll on the overall bytecode size and some operations cost more gas than if you only calculated the date and nothing else.

Or you can calculate the date manually. It's more complicated approach but it's going to be cheaper for deployment and running costs. In the end, unix timestamp is just a number of seconds from January 1st 1970, so you can calculate the amount of seconds / days / months between the time `0` and today (don't forget to account for leap years).

Example using the linked library:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import 'https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary/blob/master/contracts/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary.sol';

contract Test {
    function isTodayFirstDayOfMonth() external returns (bool) {
        /*
         * Today is May 12, so `getDay()` returns 12.
         */
        uint256 today = BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary.getDay(block.timestamp);

        return today == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help @Petr ! Small question, do you know how to return the block timestamp of the first day of the month also?